# How do I get my workspaces back?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces

I had 4 workspaces set up before I upgraded to 18.xxxx now they are gone and I can't seem to get them back. In the work I do I need those separate workspaces to keep my thinking process inline.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you install Gnome Tweaks from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

By default, 18.04 uses dynamic workspaces but if you wish to have fixed workspaces this can be achieved using Tweaks:

[image]

Be aware that in the past, the workspaces were a 'grid' of 4 but in 18.04, they are 'stacked' so you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>up or down arrow</kbd> to move from workspace to workspace.